# How to map a shell command in the lua nvim config?

Tags: lua, neovim

How to map a shell command in the lua nvim config?

`maps.n["<F4>"] = { function() io.popen("python3 " + vim.fn.expand("%")) end, desc = "Run current Python file"}`

Error:

```
E5108: Error executing lua: /home/kobe/.config/nvim/lua/core/mappings.lua:19: attempt to perform arithmetic on a string value                                                                               
stack traceback:
        /home/kobe/.config/nvim/lua/core/mappings.lua:19: in function </home/kobe/.config/nvim/lua/core/mappings.lua:19>
```

Comment: When it says "no arithmetic on strings, please", maybe you can guess that in Lua "str1 + str2" is not used? After all, Lua is a different language and it is not obliged to do everything the same way as those "pythonistas" used to. Care to read https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5 first?

Comment: This doesn't look like how you'd map a key in lua. Are you using a plugin? Probably [`which-key.nvim`](https://github.com/folke/which-key.nvim)?

Answer (score 2):

In Lua, operand to concatenate 2 strings is `..` not `+` as in Python.

Correct your code : `function() io.popen("python3 " .. vim.fn.expand("%")) end`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but I use plugins like [toggleterm](https://github.com/akinsho/toggleterm.nvim) for this. You can setup keymappings to run whatever shell command or program you want, and also have it show up in a floating or none-floating window, too.

As for just mapping it without any plugins and having the command be executing, I'm not entirely sure.